# How to get rid of horizontal scrollbar in a Grid?

Tags: wakanda

How to get rid of horizontal scrollbar in a Grid? Playing with column widths does not solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get working by entering the following in the css file for the Web Component.

```css
#{id}dataGrid1 .waf-dataGrid-body {
 overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will hide horizontal scroll bar:

```
$("#[yourGirdIDHere] .waf-dataGrid-body").css("overflow-x","hidden");
```

The side affect is that it also turns off horizontal scrolling. If the grid has columns out of bounds horizontally, it will not be able to scroll.

Comment: The Grid is located within a Web Component. I placed the following in the css file for said Web Component...    overflow-x:hidden;   It had no effect on the web page. Any suggestions? -- Thx!

Comment: Xiang, I also tried your code explicitly... $("#component1_guestMain_dataGrid1.waf-dataGrid-body").css("overflow-x","hidden");, placed a javascript file. Does not have any effect.

Comment: Look like you need a space between grid id and .waf-dataGrid-body: $("#component1_guestMain_dataGrid1 .waf-dataGrid-body").css("overflow-x","hidden"‌​);